# Is CAN ID the address of the node?

Tags: nodes, uniqueidentifier, identifier, can-bus

I'm studying CAN and CANOpen protocoll and I'm a bit confused.
The BOSCH CAN specification says:

> "The IDENTIFIER does not indicate the destination of the message, but
> describes the meaning of the data"

and its also said that there is no limitation for the number of CAN devices in a network.
However its also said that to avoid collsion CAN message IDs have to be unique in a network, which if I am correct limits the number of nodes.

**So is CAN ID an address like unique identifier of a CAN node?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the Bosch spec says, the CAN identifier tells the nature of the packet and not necessarily anything about who is the sender/receiver. All CAN messages are broadcast to all nodes. On the data link layer, all nodes will do a physical ACK of any received message, regardless if they are interested in the contents or not. Any node can in theory send any message and chose to decode any read message.

Also we can't have several packets with the same identifier but different data sizes. Nor should the system be designed so that multiple nodes risk sending the same packet at the same time. This is because message arbitration doesn't take the data portion in account, so if the identifier is the same but the data varies, then we get packet collisions.

---

As for CANopen, it is an application layer which in many situations uses low level CAN frames as carriers of higher layer protocols. In CANopen, the concept of addressable nodes was added, which isn't a requirement from CAN itself. Typically CAN will send messages as a CAN identifier plus node id. Like for example the PDO protocol: some TPDO1 using the default CAN identifier of 0x180 + node id. So node 1 will as default send 0x181 for TPDO1, node 2 will send 0x182 and so on. These are however just default settings and can often be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The CAN ID is more like a message type which anyone on the bus can pick up. The CAN messages does not include the source/destination addresses of a message.

(However If your control everything on the bus, you can encode the source/destnation in the CAN ID if you want to - it's your responsiibility then how to do that)

Answer (score 1):

> So is CAN ID an address like unique identifier of a CAN node?

No CAN ID is not a unique identifier of a CAN node. A node typically send and receive multiple frames with different CAN ID. Each CAN frame must have a unique identifier:

```
NODE_1 - FRAME_1 ID 0xA1 - Periodic - Sent every 100ms
NODE_1 - FRAME_2 ID 0xA2 - Periodic - Sent every 100ms
NODE_1 - FRAME_3 ID 0xA3 - Periodic - Sent every 100ms
NODE_2 - FRAME_1 ID 0xA3 - Periodic - Sent every 100ms
```

A typical node will send multiple frames with different CAN ID. In Automotive for example, ECUs send from a dozen to several dozen of CAN frames on a regular basis, each of them having their own CAN ID.

In the CAN 2.0 protocol, on the physical layer, the identifier represent the priority of a CAN frame. If 2 frames are sent by 2 different nodes at the exact same time, there will be an arbitration and the frame with the lowest priority will mute itself, allowing the frame with higher priority be sent first. It will try to emit again a little while later.

Usually, frames with high priorities have a short periodicity and frames with low priorities have a longer period.

```
0x001 - Very high priority frame ID, usually with a small periodicity like 10ms
...
0x7FF - Very low priority frame ID, periodicity typically 1 second or 5 seconds
```